Finland sauna heater wiring issues
I'm working on a harvia sauna heater (hsp904mxw) and a control unit for it (cx1004xw01) and I'm having some issues wiring it up. Shown options for wiring are 400v 3 phase, 230v 3 phase and 230v single phase. I cant seem to get it to work. Seems like every option they show for wiring it requires a neutral. If anyone did one of these or similar here in the US please let me know.
1st pic is the controller unit:

2nd pic is the diagram for the heater itself:

3rd pic is the controller schematic:


"Seems like every option they show for wiring it requires a neutral." The middle configuration in your second picture: "230 V/240 V/3~" does not require a neutral.

@Triplefault, how does that help a person in North America, where three-phase residential power isn't a thing?

It's a clarification of Jakeb's original diagnosis. Jakeb says there's no "no-neutral" configuration, but there is one. As to the USA setup, my comment doesn't address that part of the question. Bart's answer below seems to do that well.

This controller is designed for the European power grid, which uses 3-phases in a Y configuration, with 230V between each phase and N and 400V between the separate phases.
As the control board has a wiring option for 230V single phase, it is also possible to wire it for the US power system, especially given the fact that it also has a wiring option without neutral.
For wiring in the US, use a 240V breaker (and wire size) that is capable of supplying the current that the heater needs in the listed 230V single-phase configuration. Then connect one hot to the terminals designated L1 in that configuration and the other hot to the terminals designated N.
Even though you are connecting a hot wire to a terminal that seems to be meant for neutral, in this particular case that is fine and the electronics will not care.

That's what I did and the display/leds wouldn't even light up. Don't they need a neutral to operate correctly? I reached out to harvia twice and each time got a different answer. First one was similar to yours and the next one from a different rep that it won't work at all in the US

In the 230V 3-phase configuration there is also no neutral. Are you sure you have 240V available at the control board and not that your two hots are on the same leg (so 0V difference)?

That is a good point. Yes I'm sure I was getting 240 to it.
